# Installing anaconda - wrong “SHA-256” checksum?

Tags: 22.04, anaconda

I want to install anaconda on Ubuntu 22.04 following this instruction: https://linuxhint.com/install-anaconda-ubuntu-22-04/

In step 3, I used the following code:

```
$ curl --output anaconda.sh https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2022.05-Linux-x86_64.sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  658M  100  658M    0     0  1260k      0  0:08:55  0:08:55 --:--:-- 1097k
```

At the end of step 3, one is supposed to check the sha256 checksum and compare it to the online register. In my case, these codes differ:

```
$ sha256sum anaconda.sh
a7c0afe862f6ea19a596801fc138bde0463abcbce1b753e8d5c474b506a2db2d  anaconda.sh
```

While online (https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/) for the same version:

```
Anaconda3-2022.05-Linux-x86_64.sh   658.8M  2022-05-10 13:22:00 a01150aff48fcb6fcd6472381652de04
```

Does anyone have an idea why this is the case and if this is a problem?

Comment: That's strange...  It's possible that you somehow didn't download the entire file -- maybe it got corrupted.  I'm tempted to say "don't worry about it" since you clearly got the file from the source.  But such advice goes against the purpose of the sha256 checksum.  You can try downloading it again or download another file to see if the checksums match.  Honestly, you don't need to follow the instructions at that linuxhint.com site; you can just download it from its web site:  https://anaconda.org/ .  And then follow the instructions on this official site.

Comment: When downloading the file from anaconda.org, I run into exactly the same problem with exactly the same non-matching checksum.

Comment: Both seem to be within the anaconda.com domains, but I certainly would trust going through the web site a little bit more.  Enough to proceed with the install, if the checksums matched.  But good that you found out the mismatch and will contact them about it!

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that there are two different places where anaconda posts their checksums and they differ in the checksum for this installation file:

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/hashes/all/

```
Anaconda3-2022.05-Linux-x86_64.sh | 658.8 MiB | 2022-05-10 14:22:00 | a7c0afe862f6ea19a596801fc138bde0463abcbce1b753e8d5c474b506a2db2d
-- | -- | -- | --
```

https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/

```
Anaconda3-2022.05-Linux-x86_64.sh | 658.8M | 2022-05-10 13:22:00 | a01150aff48fcb6fcd6472381652de04
-- | -- | -- | --
```

So, it seems to be a problem on their end and I will contact them.